# Link List add function not working as expected

Tags: c, linked-list

I was learning data structures in C and thought of implementing the same,
below is the code and its giving weird output, its displaying correct data when displayed in add record function but when the same function is called from main the values are changed, I know its related to call by value but can't figure out the exact reason.

PS: sorry if the program is too long or not as per the standards

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct record;
typedef struct record data_record;

struct record{
    int data;
    struct record *next_record;
};

// forward function declarations 
data_record *get_record();
void initialize_record(data_record *,int);
void display_record(data_record *);
void display_list(data_record *,int);
data_record *generate_link_list(data_record *,int);
void add_record(data_record *,data_record,int);

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    printf("Initializing the data ... \n");
    printf("Data length: %d \n",sizeof(data_record));   
    int array_length = 5;

    data_record *start;
    // generate_list function
    start = generate_link_list(start,array_length);
    printf("------------------------------------\n\n");
    display_list(start,array_length);
    printf("Address : %x \n",start);

    // add the extra item to the existing list 
    data_record record;
    record.data = 100;
    record.next_record = NULL;  
    add_record(start,record,2);
    display_list(start,array_length +1);

    printf("Terminating the program \n");
    return 0;
}

data_record *get_record()
{
    return (data_record *)malloc(sizeof(data_record));
}

void initialize_record(data_record *record,int data)
{
    record->data = data;
    record->next_record = NULL;
}

void display_record(data_record *record)
{
    printf("Printing data: \t");
    printf("Data: %d \t",record->data);
    printf("Next Item address: %x \n",record->next_record);
}

void display_list(data_record *list,int length)
{
    data_record *list_pointer = list;
    printf("Printing the list: \n");
    int index;  
    for(index = 0;index < length;index++)
    {
        display_record(list_pointer);
        list_pointer = list_pointer->next_record;
    }
    printf("Done with the printing \n");
}

data_record *generate_link_list(data_record *list,int array_length)
{
    list = get_record();
    initialize_record(list,0);
    data_record *current_record_pointer, *record;
    int index = 0;

    current_record_pointer = list;

    printf("First record: ");   
    display_record(current_record_pointer);

    for(index = 1;index < array_length;index ++)
    {
        record = get_record();
        initialize_record(record,index);
        current_record_pointer->next_record = record;
        current_record_pointer = record;
    }
    return list;
}

void add_record(data_record *list,data_record record,int position)
{
    printf("Start address %x \n",list);
    printf("New record address %x \n",&record);
    data_record *list_pointer = list;
    int list_position = 0;
    for(list_position = 0;list_position < position - 1;list_position ++)
    {
        list_pointer = list_pointer->next_record;   
    }
    if(list_pointer != NULL)
    {
        data_record *next_record = list_pointer->next_record;
        list_pointer->next_record = &record;
        record.next_record = next_record;   
    }
    display_list(list,6);   
}
```

display_list when called from add function shows correct but the same when called from main after the add function the values are changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `record` passed to `add_record` is a copy of the `record` in `main`. That's how pass-by-value works when the parameter is a structure. So changes to `record` only affect the copy, not the original.

To fix the problem, declare `record` as a pointer

```
void add_record(data_record *list,data_record *record,int position)
{
    ...

    list_pointer->next_record = record;
    record->next_record = next_record;   

    ...
}
```

and pass the address of the record in `main`

```
add_record(start,&record,2);
```

---

Side note: it's pointless to pass the `start` to `generate_link_list` since the `start` doesn't contain any information that `generate_link_list` needs or uses. So change it to:

```
data_record *generate_link_list(int array_length)
{
    data_record *list = get_record();

    ...
}
```

---

Another note: As pointed out by @JonathanLeffler in the comments, you should always use the `get_record` function to create records. I would go farther and say that `get_record` and `initialize_record` should be combined into a single function `create_record`, e.g.

```
data_record *create_record(int data)
{
    data_record *record = malloc(sizeof(data_record));
    if ( record ) 
    {
        record->data = data;
        record->next_record = NULL;
    }
}
```

Then the code in `main` becomes

```
// add the extra item to the existing list 
data_record *record = create_record(100);
if (record)
    add_record(start,record,2);
display_list(start,array_length +1);
```

By using `create_record` for all of the records in the list, you can safely `free` the items in the list when needed.

Comment: If you're really observant, you'll note that there is a `data_record record;` defined in `main()` and passed to `add_record()` by address in the revised code.  That will work OK with this answer (the current program), but when you come to wanting to release the memory allocated to the list, that non-allocated record will become a source of disaster.  Make sure you uniformly allocate all nodes in the list.  If you don't, it becomes very difficult to release the memory associated with the list.